# jQuery foreignObject selection failure

Tags: jquery

Cannot select foreignObject using getElementsByTagName or jQuery.
As per my understanding, this could be because foreignObject doesn't for part of the HTML DOM as per jQuery. Is it this true?
How I can resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you target to iframe or element that will appear after DOM ready(live)? Provide jquery code you tried with markup